# Terraform - How to start/stop App service deployed using terraform

Tags: azure, docker, terraform, azure-appservice

I have an requirement to stop and start an Azure App service. following are my current implementation

1. I am using Azure Devops to deploy Docker Image first
2. Then I create an Azure App Service using the Docker image

So, if the docker image has been rebuilt, the App service doesn't show the changes until we stop and start the App service

what could be solution here?

Answer (score 0):

- You can stop/start the app service using the Portal.

1. *Login to Azure Portal*
2. *Goto the **app service** that you want to start/stop*
3. *In the **JSON** view change the state from **Running** to **Stopped***
4. *Also you can do it from **scmSiteAlsoStopped** property and set **False** to **True**.*

[image]